# Rejecting and editing an edit suggestion after using daily SE reviews shows Community as the rejector but not me

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, suggested-edits

Today the Suggested Edits queue has had the red dot several different times. This, of course, extends my daily review limit to 40 while the queue is overflowing.

I've noticed something interesting: when I've used up my daily 20 reviews for Suggested Edits, and the queue was overflowing when I *started* reviewing the item, but not when I *finished* reviewing it and submitted my review, my action is not recorded.

I can see why this would happen, but it causes a weird issue when I choose to reject and edit. It records the community user as rejecting the suggestion, but it does not record me as choosing reject and edit. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22737567)'s a recent example:

[image]

It *does* show the community user as rejecting with the whole "does not fix critical issues with the post" reason, but it does *not* show me as the reject-and-editor. This has happened multiple times and seems to be a recurring issue.

I'd expect something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22738887) instead:

[image]

**Could this be... a bug?**

Comment: Interesting. I don't see that review in [your review history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10388629/pikachu-the-purple-wizard?tab=activity).

Comment: Looking at the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55657656/timeline) for that post it is obvious that you rejected and edited at `2019-04-12 23:09:19Z` so it's weird that that has happened.

Comment: @WaiHaLee that's the weird thing: I haven't been recorded as performing the review, but my edit still went through and the community user is still shown as having rejected the edit with the reject and edit message.

Comment: This is a bad bug in terms of accountability. I don't like Community taking responsibility, you can't tell who did what anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent of you "force editing" a post with a pending review. As the queue reset to the limit of 20, you're unable to review any further. The Community user *does* reject edits that if there was an edit since, which is what is happening here. Since you're no longer able to review (as the queue limit decreased), the system doesn't let you register that as a review. It does, however, let you edit the post anyways, causing the potential conflict and subsequent rejection by the Community user. As you can't review any further, that's also why it doesn't show in your review history (as noted in the comments).

Apparently the edit rejection doesn't take effect until you've submitted the edit, which would be the issue at hand. I don't know if there is any particular reasoning behind this, but this *specific* situation leads to an odd outcome.